# Mock of promise based method is not working

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Trying to write a tests in **JEST** for my node.js written in typescript. The function which I want to test is very complex (I mean a lot of stuff are happening inside). It returns a **Promise** and inside it there are 2 other functions which are returning a **Promises** (one of it it's making async call) + the are **BehaviorSubject**, **Observables**  (created with **forEach** from an array) with **forkJoin** .

I'm trying to mock the response of 1 of the nested **Promise** based function. The result of it is assign to an **Observable**. The reason why I'm trying to change the response of it is because I want to test my master function.

The problems which I'm facing are that when I'm creating the mock of the async function the test on the master function looks like it's ignoring my mock and going to the original one.

Here is an example (try to simplify it) of my module:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'

export const tableConfig: any[] = [{
    tableName: 'TableOne'
},
{
    tableName: 'TableTwo'
},
{
    tableName: 'TableThree'
}];

const exampleApiTableData: any = {
    TableOne: [],
    TableTwo: [],
    TableThree: [],
}

export const pullTableData = (tableName: string): Promise<any[]> => { //async Promise function 1
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Here is a async api call with some more logic but to make it simple and short giving such an example
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(exampleApiTableData[tableName]);
        }, 1000);
    })
}

export const buildNewTable = (tableOne: any[], tableTwo: any []): Promise<any[]> => { // Promise function 2
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //simplified example
        resolve(tableOne.concat(tableTwo));
    })
}

export const getTables = (): Promise<any> => { // Master
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const errors: string[] = [];
        const allTableData$: any[] = [];
        const observableNames: any = {};

        tableConfig.forEach(table => {
            observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'] = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>([]);
            observableNames[table.tableName] = observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'].asObservable();
            allTableData$.push(observableNames[table.tableName]);
            pullTableData(table.tableName).then((result: any[]) => {
                observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'].next(result);
                observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'].complete();
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                errors.push(error);
                observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'].next(error);
                observableNames[table.tableName + 'Source'].complete();
            })
        });

        forkJoin(allTableData$).subscribe((results: any) => {
            if (errors.length > 0) reject(errors);
            buildNewTable(observableNames.TableOneSource.value, observableNames.TableTableTwoSource.value).then((result: any[]) => {
                // console.log(result);
                resolve(result);
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                // console.log(error);
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This is the test I created but instead of getting the **mockRejectedValue** value it's calling **pullTableData** all the time

```
import * as tableMethods from './index'

describe(`Test the Table methods`, () => {
    test(`it should return and error`, () => {
        const expectedError = `I'm an error`
        jest.fn(tableMethods.pullTableData).mockRejectedValue(expectedError);

        return tableMethods.getTables().then((data: any) => {

        }).catch((error: any) => {
            expect(error).toBe(expectedError);
        })
    })
})
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Is there a way to mock the **pullTableData** and the **buildNewTable** so I can test the **getTable** function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a couple of code changes:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, forkJoin } from 'rxjs'
import * as index from './index';  // <= import module into itself

// ...    

export const getTables = (): Promise<any> => { // Master

  // ...

      index.pullTableData(table.tableName).then((result: any[]) => {  // <= call pullTableData using the module

  // ...

      if (errors.length > 0) reject(new Error(errors.join(', ')));  // <= reject using an Error object

  // ...
}
```

...then you can test it like this:

```
import * as tableMethods from './index'

describe(`Test the Table methods`, () => {
  test(`it should return and error`, async () => {  // <= async test function
    const expectedError = `I'm an error`
    jest.spyOn(tableMethods, 'pullTableData').mockRejectedValue(expectedError);  // <= use jest.spyOn

    await expect(tableMethods.getTables()).rejects.toThrow(`I'm an error, I'm an error, I'm an error`);  // Success!
  })
})
```

---

**Details**

Mocking a function using something like `jest.spyOn` replaces the *module export* for the function.

In this case `getTables` was calling `pullTableData` directly, so mocking the module export for `pullTableData` wasn't having any effect.

TypeScript and ES6 modules [support cyclic dependencies automatically](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_cyclic-dependencies-in-ecmascript-6) so you can import a module into itself in order to call the *module export* for the function so that when the module export is mocked the mocked function is called instead of the original.

Best practice is to always `reject` using an `Error` object.

Rejecting with an `Error` object also allows you to use `.rejects.toThrow` in your test.

Using [`rejects`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#rejects) and [`resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) requires you to either return the `Promise` from the `expect` or to use an `async` test function and `await` the `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Instead of `await expect(tableMethods.getTables()).rejects ...` I use `return tableMethods.getTables().catch....` 
Not sure if I should create a new question or update my existing one but if I want to use a mock function for pullTableData (create a folder __mocks__ and add functionality there) how should I mock it ? Currently we are creating a spyOn and mocking the response (mockRejectedValue)

Comment: can it be moved into its own module?  That would make it a lot easier to create a manual mock for it.  @Kosmonaft